# ASP.NET MVC sitemap for a traditional hierarchical site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have tried to use http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/ but i can't get it to work with an hierarchical structure from the database... with that said, does anyone know of any other site map provider or can use?

Answer (score 0):

Telerik's open source mvc extensions support sitemaps.

For sitemaps with a panel bar see http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/panelbar/sitemapbinding

and for a treeview see http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/sitemapbinding

I don't know if these are useful in your case

Comment: It's not quite what I'm looking for, it's not so complicated to write my own sitemapprovider though

Answer (score 0):

I use this provider:

http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/

Works great and is pretty simple.

You might want to post on their group to get more specific help.